# Reprojecting a CSV file using ogr2ogr?

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, vrt

I am trying to convert a CSV with fields in one projection system (EPSG:27700) to fields in another (EPSG:4326).

I have made a VRT file called `landfill.vrt`, in the same directory as my CSV file, `landfill.csv`:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="landfill">
    <SrcDataSource>/Users/me/Downloads/landfill.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>EPSG:27700</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="ctroid_x" y="ctroid_y"/>
  </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

ogrinfo seems to think it's OK:

```
$ ogrinfo -ro -al landfill.vrt
... 
OGRFeature(landfill):2010
  ctroid_x (String) = 567600
  ctroid_y (String) = 314500
  region (String) = Anglian
  area (String) = Central
  date_issue (String) = 21/10/10
  POINT (567600 314500)
```

But when I run `ogr2ogr`:

```
 $ ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:4326 
  -f CSV -lco "GEOMETRY=AS_WKT" ./output/output.csv landfill.csv
```

it runs cleanly, but just outputs a copy of the original file to `output/output.csv`, without any new fields. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you really want to do is to convert landfill.vrt into output.csv.

Comment: Yes! Thank you :) if you want to submit that as an answer, please do...

Comment: Does not feel much like an answer. You would have noticed it by yourself after having a break.

Comment: It still might help future users who find this question, and it would take it out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answered by [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) in comments section:**

> What you really want to do is to convert landfill.vrt into output.csv.